# Laravel - SUM and balane query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a Laravel application. I am trying calculate the SUM of column and balance. Can you please help me how to write the SQL for this.

```
+---------+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
| pay_id  | username | income | outgoings| balance  |     date   |
+---------+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
|    1    |   john   |  1000  |          |   1000   | 00.00.2016 |
|    2    |   jack   |        |   500    |    500   | 00.00.2016 |
|    3    |   john   |  1500  |          |   2000   | 00.00.2016 |
|    4    |   bill   |        |  1000    |   1000   | 00.00.2016 |
+---------+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
                        2500     1500
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Also, it's not clear if you are looking for a way to get a computed `balance` column, or if you want a row-wise sum of the `income` and `outgoings` columns.

Comment: I've tried nothing. I dont know where to start

Comment: if you are using laravel eloquent, getting sum is like this DB::table('tableName')->sum('balance');

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eloquent:

```
Model::where('username', 'john')->sum('balance');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum multiple columns then you have to us `DB::raw`

```
$data = Model::get([
        DB::raw('SUM(income) AS total_income'),
        DB::raw('SUM(outgoings) AS total_outgoings'),
        DB::raw('SUM(balance) AS total_balance')
    ]);
dd($data);
```

Or

```
$data = Model::select(
        DB::raw('SUM(income) AS total_income'), 
        DB::raw('SUM(outgoings) AS total_outgoings'), 
        DB::raw('SUM(balance) AS total_balance')
    )
    ->get();
dd($data);
```